# grub-common is not available after waking up from hibernate

Tags: grub2, hibernate, wakeup

I have seen that after a normal boot grub-common unsets the recordfail and enters exited status (I don't see the process running any more).

After I hibernate and wake up the system (it wakes up correctly), since grub-common is not running, recordfail keeps on. I believe grub-common should be running as a daemon and should not exit.

Is there a way to achieve this by changing the grub-common.service parameters?

```
[Unit]
Documentation=man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
SourcePath=/etc/init.d/grub-common
Description=LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB
Before=multi-user.target
Before=multi-user.target
Before=multi-user.target
Before=graphical.target

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/grub-common start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/grub-common stop
```

Since recordfail is not been unset, the next wake up stops at grub. My workaround is a recordfail_timeout=0 in grub.cfg but I would like to have a working (not in exit status) grub-common that unsets rhe recordfail in grubenv as it should do.

Details of the process:
 Grub always sets recordfail (also at wake from hibernate) grub-common does the unset after the boot - or wake up - ends correctly. If grub-common is not running after the wake up then recordfail keeps exiting (I see it with grub-editenv list). That means that by the next wake up form hibernate GRUB finds a recordfail in grubenv and stops in the menu (unless you set recordfail_tim.eout=0. But... thats not the issue. The question is why grub-common.service exits. If the service would keep on running he would unset the recordfail in grubenv.
(i have tested it : stopped and started grub-common manually and the recordfail entry in grubenv dissapears).

As a resumee: Does somebody knows how to start a service with a Daemon character? (not exiting but keeping alive and kicking)

Comment: Can you tell us what is not working after you hibernate? ie no mouse, no screen, etc.? If grub itself works by having certain functions run at certain times and not run at other times it's not a bug unless it breaks something. You haven't said what is broken.

Comment: nothing is broken but... since recordfail is not been unset, the next wake up stops at grub. My workaround is a recordfail_timeout=0 in grub.cfg but.. I would like to have a working grub-common (dont like the timeout workaround)

Comment: GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT

Comment: I knew that already but... thats not my question. grub-common should keep on running. Do you know what I can do in order to keep it running?

Comment: ^^ that last comment was a work in progress that can't be edited after 5 minutes.  `recordfail` is used during boot to select default menu option. It should not effect resuming from hibernation because no grub menu is presented then. I hope you can modify your question to clarify why `recordfail` is important at resume.  As far as `grub-common` goes I've just done a little reading about `/usr/lib/pm-utils/bin/pm-action` but hope you can clarify why it is important during resume so I can narrow the research. @Zanna thanks for edit OP's question with suitable code blocks :)

Comment: Sorry but that is not my understanding. Grub always sets recordfail (also at wake from hibernate) grub-common does the unset after the boot - or wake up - ends correctly.  If grub-common is not running after the wake up then recordfail keeps exiting (I see it with grub-editenv list). That means that by the next wake up form hibernate GRUB finds a recordfail in grubenv and stops in the menu (unless you set recordfail_tim. eout=0). But... thats not the issue. The question is why grub-common.service exits. If the service would keep on running he would unset the recordfail in grubenv.

Comment: (i have tested it : stopped and started grub-common manuall and the recordfail entry in grubenv dissapears.

Comment: Thank you for your comments elaborating the process. Now I understand the original question and problem better. Is it safe to simply things as  "Hibernation makes grub think last boot failed" or something like that?

Comment: You are right. I am dealing with this a while until i discovered that the problem lies in grub-common. If i had only spoken about "grub think that the last boot failed" no one would think about grub-common (Thats my opinion) Its also not a problem about "the last boot" but about the last wake from hibernate with a death "grub-common". A question: should I move this dicussion to a chat? (as Proposed)?

Comment: It would be great if you can somehow roll all our comments into your question (by using `Edit` button) to make it clear as possible for people reading the question to understand the problem.

Comment: YIKES!!! I didn't mean to copy and paste all my comments into your question. I meant to summarize your comments into the question--take relevant details from your comments and clarify the question. Could you please `Edit` again with this in mind?

Comment: Solved through https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2333934

Comment: CONGRATULATIONS! I see you've posted a comment in the link requesting the OP to report it as a bug. Well done :) The next step is to answer your own question. I'll upvote your answer and you can mark the answer as solved.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible the way I thought. The reason is that after Ubuntu 15.04 the init process is working with systemd which uses system units for the start process. Under https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2333934 You may find a tutorial how to setup a system unit in order to unset the recordfail after a succesfull resume form hibernate. I have also seen that the canonical team is migrating the old services to systemd so I hope that in the near  future they will deliver the "official" solution